# JPA nullable=false option is not propagated to the SQL schema generation script

Tags: sql, jpa, database-schema, nullable

I specify a JPA entity attribute with `nullable = false`:

```java
@Entity
class EntityName {
  // ...

  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(127)")
  protected String uName;

  // ...
}
```

However, the `NOT NULL` does not appear in the schema generation script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EntityName (..., UNAME VARCHAR(127), ...)
```

(I create the schema generation script in Eclipse 2019-12 from a project context menu with the <kbd>JPA Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Generate Tables from Entities...</kbd> > <kbd>Sql-script</kbd> option.)

Why does that happen? I expect that the `UNAME` column is `NOT NULL` in the SQL statement...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `columnDefinition` option of your [`@Column`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation:

```java
columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(127)"
```

The `columnDefinition` essentially overrides everything that could have been generated.
So, the `NOT NULL` from the `nullable = false` has just been lost. (It looks like that is left unspecified by the JPA standard, though.)

You can overcome that by writing:

```java
columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL"
```